# Max and min value per hour Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to return Max/Min value per hour in postgresql. Her is my code for max/min per day.

```
@"SELECT MAX(psa_value), MIN(psa_value),DATE(psa_date) FROM public.ps_analog Where psa_psl_id_name='A6' GROUP BY DATE(psa_date)";
```

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you. Showing how to do daily does not count as showing effort in solving your problem (hourly). As a hint research how to round a date, in this case round hourly. Your problem should then be trivial.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', psa_date) as hh, MAX(psa_value), MIN(psa_value)
FROM public.ps_analog 
WHERE psa_psl_id_name = 'A6'
GROUP BY hh;
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try that solution.